# Is it possible to Deep link to App Clips (iOS) from a third-party / trusted apps?

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, apple-appclips

From my App Clip, I want to use a third-party / trusted app for authentication, this will lead the user to switch from App Clip to a third-party app where the user will authenticate himself and the third-party app should be able to deep-link / switch to App Clip once the authentication is successful.

The question here is whether it is possible for a third-party app to return back the user to the App Clip? If yes, how?

I have also posted this question on the developer forum and haven't received any response yet.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/680267

Appreciate anyone's prompt response/suggestion on this. Thank You :)

Comment: This is a pretty interesting question but App Clips are pretty new and information about them is scarce. Have you tried doing this yourself? What have you tried and what was the outcome?

Comment: Hi @EmilioPelaez, thank you. I tried to add appClips & appLinks to associated domains, however, when I navigated to the third party app and tried invoking the App Clips with the associated domain did not work.

Comment: Have you tried using a URL scheme?

Comment: Sure, let me give it a try.

Comment: Hi @EmilioPelaez, I tried the URL scheme, but it did not work for App Clips. However, it worked for the main app. Also, as per the Apple documentation, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app, on URL Schemes possess some vulnerabilities and as per some threads and Apple, universal links are preferred. I also tried universal links (app links), it still, did not work. Please let me know if you have any other suggestions?

Comment: That's the extent of my suggestions. I would suggest you contact Apple through the developer account code review request or whatever it is called. If there's a way, they'll help you find out or just tell you that it's not possible.

Comment: did it work for you? I want to open app Clip from custom scheme urls but it is not working, but it is working for the main application

Comment: Can't get it work. Looks like bug, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71568891/universal-link-or-url-scheme-for-app-clip-to-link-back-from-email