# Universal link or URL scheme for App Clip to link back from email

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links, apple-appclips

We are building an App Clip that comes with some sign up functionality. Beside `Sign in with Apple` users can also sign up with email.

In order to proceed they need to confirm a link in an email that has been sent to the address used for signing up. The universal link works perfectly fine for the full app, so the AASA file and associated domains are working.

However, we can not link back to the App Clip which is a major break in the user flow and it's very likely that users are not able to return to the App Clip.

Is there any way to link from an email back to the App Clip?

Comment: did you fix it ?

Comment: I want to open my App Clip with custom scheme urls, is it possible ?

Comment: Same issue. Can't find solution.